SQL Inner join with where clause works fast with one condition, but not when activeFlag is added
I have a query like
select C.customerId, C.firstName, C.LastName, R.IsActive 
from Customer as C
Inner join Rider as R ON R.customerId = C.customerid
where R.rideid = 'xyz' 
    and R.rideareacode = 'abc' 
    and R.isActive = 1

This is taking too much like 90 seconds or more. But if I remove the R.IsActive = 1 condition query is taking only a second.
IsActive has only two values 1 or 0, also the Customer and Rider table are big (80k rows)
I tried indexing the IsActive column of my Rider table but still the query is taking too much, I also tried indexing (rideid, rideareacode, isActive) still it is taking too long.
Index_keys for Rider table :
IsActive (nonclustered)
rideid, rideareacode, isActive, userid (nonclustered, unique)
riderid (nonclustered, unique, primary key)

There is no indexing for the customers table.
Update on Solution that worked for me:
I just ran sp_updatestats and all the queries are now running in under a second, what did I do ? Sure, the command fixed my problems, but in the future does this create any problems ? Using this info what was the original reason the queries (there are other queries as well related to the tables I mentioned) are slow.

Are rider.customerid and customer.customerid indexed?

No, but I don't think that is reason why query is slow. Because if I remove the R.isActive = 1 condition, the query runs perfectly fine in a second.

Please update your question with the DDL (including indexes) for your tables and the EXPLAIN PLANs for the queries with/without the IsActive column

what explain sql_query says with isActive=1 in place?

Do try indexing your ID field. While you are not using it the ID field in an explicit "where" clause, it is being used to join the columns which is very much a filter. You are likely hitting a buffer barrier with the "active" addition to the query which pushes it to a different method of storage. But you may drop back within that barrier by indexing the join fields.

I tried creating index on customerId for customer table, but getting this error message : Cannot create index on 'Customers' because the view is not schema bound.

When I ran the query with Explain I am getting the error message : Could not find stored procedure 'explain'.  But I could see that the query results without any issues.

"riderid (nonclustered, unique, primary key)" -- Eh?  In MySQL, the PRIMARY KEY is, by definition` clustered and unique.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables.

Don't put the solution in the question. Post it below in the Answer section.

One of the two tables I was using for the join operation is a view, when I dug deep into the view I found that R.customerid is of type string so there is conversion like try_cast(customerid as decimal(10)), because C.customerid is of type numeric(10). Although I found that decimal and numeric types to be almost same, run time for my existing query is >= 1 minute, when I changed decimal in try_cast(customerid as decimal(10)) to numeric to match my C.customerid type, my query ran in 1 sec.

R needs INDEX(rideid, rideareacode, isActive), with the columns in any order.
Even better is this "covering index":
INDEX(rideid, rideareacode, isActive,  -- in any order
      customerId)                      -- after the others

And C needs customerId indexed -- Perhaps it is already the PRIMARY KEY, which is an index.

The customer table is inside the Views, so I could not create index on the customer table as I am getting cannot create index on view 'Customers' because the view is not schema bound. How can I do the indexing for Customers ? I already indexed the Rider table as you mentioned.

@Rancha124 make sure all of those fields are in the same index. Indexing each column separately won't help you.

@Rancha124 - Sounds like we need to see the CREATE VIEW to help you further.


I tried indexing the IsActive column of my Rider table

You want one Rider  index for RideId, RideAreaCode, IsActive, and CustomerId all in the same index, and in that order.
You might be able to switch the area code and ride id, but this is the idea. Indexing each column individually does not help when a query needs to use more than one column.

Besides modifying the indexes, you can also add the conditions to the ON clause:
select C.customerId, C.firstName, C.LastName, R.IsActive from
Customer as C
Inner join Rider as R ON R.customerId = C.customerid and
           R.rideid = 'xyz' and
           R.rideareacode = 'abc' and 
           R.isActive = 1


I don't think the query planner treats this any different.
